# How to delete entity from database

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, entity

i am new on hibernate-spring tirple..

i just try to code simple register book.. i have following codes:

Student.java

```
@Entity(name = "STUDENTS")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "getAllStudent", query = "SELECT k FROM STUDENTS k ORDER BY k.id DESC"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "findByName", query = "SELECT k FROM STUDENTS k WHERE k.name LIKE :name")
})
public class Student {

    @Column(name = "STUDENTNO", nullable = false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "SURNAME")
    private String surname;
    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private String age;
    // GET ve SET metods
```

StduentDAO.java

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class StudentDAO implements IStudentDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
        public void deleteStudent(Student student) {
        Student temp = em.getReference(Student.class, student.getId());
        em.remove(temp);
        System.out.println("### getting out from studentDAO deleteStudent method ###")
```

StudentController.java

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "request")
public class StudentController {

@Autowired
IStudentDAO studentDAO;
List<Student> allStudentList = new ArrayList();
Student student = new Student();

@PostConstruct
 private void loadStudents() {
 allStudentList = studentDAO.allStudent();

 public void deleteStudent() {
 studentDAO.deleteStudent(student);
 System.out.println("### getting out from StudentController deleteStudent method ### ");
 }
```

When I run `deleteStudent()` codes i am getting:

"### getting out from studentDAO deleteStudent method ###"

"### getting out from StudentController deleteStudent method ### "

i see these on output but nothing is deleting from database.. i searched a bit and i found this "every entitiy manager's methods open own session." that is why it says i should write my StudentDAO's deleteStudent methof like above..

i think i am missing something about transaciton but i have not recognized yet..

what should i do about this ?

Thanks..

Comment: Why you use @Transactional(readOnly = true)??? readOnly = true doesn't delete. Tell me if it's OK so I convert this comment in answer.

Comment: i deleted " @Transactional(readOnly = true)" and run again. Got same results.. i got  getting out output message from methods but nothing was deleted

Comment: i also should  add nothing about @Transactional annotation or it was wrong place and wrong parameter ?

Comment: @Transactional must be remain remove only readOnly = true

Comment: Thnks this solved problem.. You can mark as solved..

Comment: Ok, I've created an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Transactional annotation create a transaction on your DBMS.

If you use (readOnly = true) you prevent operation on your DB (as INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE).

Remove readOnly = true so your delete method will work.